# Having an hard time carrying out user input validation with Yup and Formik

Tags: reactjs, redux, formik, yup

I want to carry out form validation using Yup and Formik. The minimum length and empty fields check are working properly but an trying to replace special characters entered into the form with htmlEntities has not been successful as the characters still get transmitted into the database. Please kindly help see what I am probably doing wrong. Thanks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "./features/posts/postSlice";
import { createPost } from "./features/poststextonly/postSlice";
import {Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const sanitizeInput = (input) => {
const regex = /[<>&"']/g;
const htmlEntities = {
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '&': '&amp;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#x27;',
  '/': '&#x2F',
};
return input.replace(regex, (match) => htmlEntities[match]);
}

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  pst: Yup.string().min(10, 'Post must be at least 10 characters').required("Field cannot be empty").transform(sanitizeInput),
})

const NewPostForm = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const handleSubmit = (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
    dispatch(createPost(values));
    setSubmitting(false);
    dispatch(getPosts());
   }

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{pst: ''}} validationSchema={schema} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {({isSubmitting, errors, touched}) => (
        <div className="col-12 mt-1 mb-1">
        <div className="form col-12 mb-0">
          <Form>
            <div className="form-group mb-0 pb-0 ">
              <Field
                as="textarea"
                name="pst"
                id="pst"
                // value={values.pst}
                // onChange={(e) => setPst(e.target.value)}
                className={errors.message && touched.message ? 'error' : ''}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)" }}
              />
             <ErrorMessage name="pst" component="div" className="error-message bg-danger m-1 text-light" />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group mt-0 col-12 m-0 p-0">
              <button
                className="col-auto btn btn-sm rounded-1 p-1"
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: "auto",
                  marginRight: "0",
                }}
              >
                {isSubmitting ? "Submitting..." : "Submit"}
              </button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
      
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default NewPostForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. I first dispatched the replaced symbols into the database with this code

```
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldProps } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  fieldName: Yup.string()
    .required('Field is required')
    .min(10, 'Field must be at least 10 characters')
});

function MyForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleSubmit(values, { resetForm }) {
    // Replace special characters with HTML entities
    values.fieldName = values.fieldName.replace(/[&<>"']/g, (match) => {
      switch (match) {
        case '&':
          return '&amp;';
        case '<':
          return '&lt;';
        case '>':
          return '&gt;';
        case '"':
          return '&quot;';
        case "'":
          return '&#039;';
        default:
          return match;
      }
    });

    // Dispatch values to Redux slice
    dispatch(values);

    // Reset form
    resetForm();
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ fieldName: '' }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="fieldName">
            {({ field }: FieldProps) => (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="fieldName">Field Name</label>
                <textarea id="fieldName" {...field} />
                {errors.fieldName && touched.fieldName && (
                  <div>{errors.fieldName}</div>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>

          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

And then used 'he' to decode the htmlEntities back to the symbols on browser

```
npm install he
```

//In your component

```
import he from 'he';

const GetData = ({post}) => {
const decodedText = he.decode(post.post)
     return (
     {decodedText}
     );
}
```